# Can "integer" be used as an adjective?

Tags: number-theory, terminology, integers

Although "integer" in Latin means "whole", as far as I know in English it is used as a noun. Personally, I have not seen an integer "number", but only "integers". My question is that is it wrong to say
*k* is an integer "number"?

Comment: How intriguing. We do say “$x$ is real”. I guess the corresponding adjective is “$k$ is integral”, but it’s too confusing so we never say it?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's wrong but rather redundant due to the modern notion of the word.

Comment: integer "number" is redundant, isn't it?  Are there any integers that are not numbers?  I mean "if $x$ is an integer, then x is a number."  Just like "if x is real, then x is a number"...  We don't typically describe an apple as an "apple fruit", or a banana as a "banana fruit".

Comment: @amWhy but we almost always say rational numbers or even complex numbers; however, we don't say integer numbers

Comment: Integer is a nown.  rational, complex, are adjectives.  Hey, it's not an issue for me either way.  But it's not the sort of question that has a correct answer.  In that sense, it should be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: We might say that "a variable takes only integer values" which makes it feel like an adjective whether it is one or not.

Answer (score 3):

The adjective form is integral, even though this is overloaded with the word integral as it pertains to integration.

As for saying integer number, it's used as a noun here, in the sense that computer science is valid but contains two nouns.

Comment: or birthday cake

Comment: In the collocation *integer number* the OED classifies *integer* as an adjective. It also notes that this usage is rare or obsolete; its latest citation is from 1806.

Comment: No.  In "computer science" 'computer' is used as an *adjectival noun* or *attributive noun* and functions as an adjective, as in "apple pie" or "sports car."